# How to validate a JPEG encoder?

Tags: validation, jpeg

Since JPEG uses a DCTII and quantization, how can I validate a JPEG encoder I created? I set my quantization table to all 1's which would require that both my implementation and the reference one round the same, and then from there the precision of the DCTII calculation would account for any differences between my implementation and the reference if we both started with YCbCr no? How can I validate my implementation if I am unable to replicate the same precision as the DCTII used in a reference (Python's PIL or libjpeg ect.)

For context, yes I have an image and the image is very close (average difference of .2, max abs difference of 3) from a golden reference, but that isn't enough to definitely say that my implementation is correct. How could I prove that otherwise?